# Plot figures similar to ones created in MatLab patch function with free rotation

Tags: javascript, matlab, webgl

The figure:

[image: http://equake-rc.info/media/srcmod/_img_files/s2010HAITIx01CALA.png]

It was generated locally using Matlab's `patch` function.
Is it possible to create such a graph in JavaScript, and also allow free rotation. I'm open to using any available libraries for this.

Comment: Look at http://d3js.org/, there surely is some code available for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can get something quite similar with this nice javascript library I've also once used in the past: https://code.google.com/p/webgl-surface-plot/

See this example with free rotation and a nice smooth surface: http://www.grvisualisation.50webs.com/javascript_surface_plot.html

and you can even try it out here online:
jsfiddle.net/4N7jQ/1/